# Rails app outputting to console constantly, can't find source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

I have a Rails 3.2 app running on Heroku which is outputting the following 3 lines every couple of seconds.

```
Jun 20 11:03:32 xxxxxxxx app/web.1:  limit  
Jun 20 11:03:32 xxxxxxxx app/web.1:  Response class: Net::HTTPOK 
Jun 20 11:03:33 xxxxxxxx app/web.1:  Response headers: {"content-type"=>["application/json"], "date"=>["Thu, 20 Jun 2013 10:03:32 GMT"], "content-length"=>["15"], "connection"=>["keep-alive"]}
```

I have no idea where this is coming from, I can't reproduce this in development and there's nowhere in my application code I can find that's causing this.

Any idea what might be doing this, or how to find out ?

Here's the Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
    activesupport (3.2.13)
      i18n (= 0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.3.4)
    airbrake (3.1.12)
      activesupport
      builder
      json
    andand (1.3.3)
    arel (3.0.2)
    atomic (1.1.9)
    attr_required (0.0.5)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    better_errors (0.9.0)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.1)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (2.2.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bootswatch-rails (0.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    builder (3.0.4)
    butler_static (0.0.9)
      rack
      rails (>= 3.1.0)
    cache_digests (0.3.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.2)
      thread_safe
    chronic (0.9.1)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.1)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
    css_parser (1.3.4)
      addressable
    cssminify (1.0.2)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    dalli (2.6.4)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    delayed_job (3.0.5)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
    delayed_job_ironmq (1.0.1)
      delayed_job (~> 3.0.0)
      iron_mq (>= 4.0.0)
    delayed_job_null (0.0.4)
      delayed_job (~> 3.0.0)
    delorean (2.1.0)
      chronic
    devise (2.2.4)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    enum_column3 (0.1.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    excon (0.22.1)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    faraday (0.8.7)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
    fb_graph (2.7.1)
      httpclient (>= 2.2.0.2)
      multi_json (>= 1.3)
      rack-oauth2 (>= 0.14.4)
      tzinfo
    flag_shih_tzu (0.3.2)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
    fog (1.11.1)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.20)
      formatador (~> 0.2.0)
      json (~> 1.7)
      mime-types
      net-scp (~> 1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.0)
      ruby-hmac
    font-awesome-sass-rails (3.0.2.2)
      railties (>= 3.1.1)
      sass-rails (>= 3.1.1)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    geocoder (1.1.8)
    hash_extension (0.0.4)
    hashie (2.0.5)
    hike (1.2.2)
    hpricot (0.8.6)
    httparty (0.11.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    httpauth (0.2.0)
    httpclient (2.3.3)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    ipaddr_list (0.0.2)
    iron_core (0.6.2)
      rest (>= 2.2.0)
    iron_mq (4.0.3)
      iron_core (>= 0.5.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    jwt (0.1.8)
      multi_json (>= 1.5)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    kgio (2.8.0)
    lograge (0.2.0)
      actionpack
      activesupport
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    memcache-client (1.8.5)
    memcachier (0.0.2)
    meta_request (0.2.1)
      rack-contrib
      rails
    mime-types (1.23)
    multi_json (1.7.4)
    multi_xml (0.5.3)
    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    net-http-persistent (2.8)
    net-scp (1.1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.6.7)
    newrelic_rpm (3.5.7.59)
    nokogiri (1.5.9)
    oauth2 (0.8.1)
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      httpauth (~> 0.1)
      jwt (~> 0.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    oj (2.0.14)
    omniauth (1.1.4)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 3)
      rack
    omniauth-facebook (1.4.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.0.2)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.3)
      oauth2 (~> 0.8.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    paperclip (3.4.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.0)
      mime-types
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-auth-simples (0.0.10)
      ipaddr_list (>= 0.0.2)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-contrib (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.1)
    rack-oauth2 (1.0.5)
      activesupport (>= 2.3)
      attr_required (>= 0.0.5)
      httpclient (>= 2.2.0.2)
      multi_json (>= 1.3.6)
      rack (>= 1.1)
    rack-protection (1.5.0)
      rack
    rack-reverse-proxy (0.4.4)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-rewrite (1.3.3)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.13)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activerecord (= 3.2.13)
      activeresource (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.13)
    railties (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.11.0)
    rake (10.0.4)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redcarpet (2.3.0)
    redis (3.0.4)
    redis-namespace (1.3.0)
      redis (~> 3.0.0)
    rest (2.6.2)
      net-http-persistent
      rest-client (>= 0.3.0)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    roadie (2.3.4)
      actionmailer (> 3.0.0, < 3.3.0)
      css_parser
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      sprockets
    rpm_contrib (2.1.11)
      newrelic_rpm (>= 3.1.1)
      newrelic_rpm (>= 3.1.1)
    ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
    sass (3.2.9)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    simple-random (0.9.3)
    sinatra (1.3.6)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.3)
      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.3)
    split (0.6.1)
      redis (>= 2.1)
      redis-namespace (>= 1.1.0)
      simple-random
      sinatra (>= 1.2.6)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.0)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbo-sprockets-rails3 (0.3.6)
      railties (> 3.2.8, < 4.0.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.0.0)
    turbolinks (1.1.1)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    unicorn (4.6.2)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    unidecode (1.0.0)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  airbrake
  andand
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bootstrap-sass (~> 2.2.2.0)
  bootswatch-rails
  butler_static
  cache_digests
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  cssminify
  dalli
  delayed_job
  delayed_job_ironmq
  delayed_job_null
  delorean
  devise
  enum_column3
  fb_graph
  flag_shih_tzu
  fog (~> 1.9)
  font-awesome-sass-rails
  geocoder
  hash_extension (~> 0.0.4)
  hpricot (>= 0.4)
  httparty
  jquery-rails
  kaminari (~> 0.13)
  kgio
  lograge
  memcache-client
  memcachier
  meta_request (= 0.2.1)
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.2)
  newrelic_rpm (~> 3.5.7.59)
  oj
  omniauth-facebook (= 1.4.0)
  paperclip (~> 3.0)
  rack-auth-simples
  rack-reverse-proxy
  rack-rewrite
  rails (~> 3.2.8)
  redcarpet
  roadie
  rpm_contrib
  ruby-hmac (>= 0.3.2)
  sass-rails
  split
  sprockets
  thin
  turbo-sprockets-rails3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  unicorn
  unidecode
```

Comment: That looks like a ping request from an outside monitoring service - you seem to have newrelic configured, so that might be it.

Comment: grep for word limit, you'll find it.

Comment: I have grepped for the word limit, none of the matches within my app are causing this. Next up, grepping all the gems I guess

Comment: @eugen I do have New Relic configured, but it doesn't ping that frequently only every 30 seconds as I recall. This is appearing every 2 or 3 seconds, on every instance. I will however grep the newrelic gem first

Answer (score 1):

After grepping (well, [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/)ing actually) through all the gems used I found that the [rest 2.6.2 gem](https://github.com/iron-io/rest) was causing this. The log level was incorrect within that gem and an update to 2.6.3 fixes this.